# How do I sync a local rails database with a remote database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've used Taps before on Heroku, but what is a good solution on non-heroku rails apps?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a capistrano task/s to mysqldump on the source database, gzip the file, then scp it to the destination and execute the mysql script there to import.

Comment: I'm sure this problem has been solved before, and I think Taps actually does that. I've found for common problems, that if I'm writing my own solution, someone has written a better one with more revisions out there.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Capistrano recipe some time ago to sync a MySQL database and files between different environments: https://gist.github.com/111597

Answer (score -1):

OK, there are some things you need to keep in mind. If you are using SQlite for development and MySQL / Postgre for production on the server, then sinking is almost impossible. On the contrary if you are using the same DB engines you can use administrator interface like MySQL administrator on your desktop  and generate a backup file and upload it to server and vice versa.

May hosting providers provide PHPMyAdmin to take backups and restore it on the server.

Comment: This approach isn't really syncing, and is a bit cumbersome.